# RecyclerView messing up indices

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a `RecyclerView`, and after I scroll, the values of my items in my `adapter` are swapping. This is obviously an issue with the recycling of the view, with the underlying data not being cleared.

However, i've read dozens of iterations of this question, but am unable to decipher a clear fix from any of the answers, and my problem is persisting.

I am setting the `Adapter` to have Stable Ids, overriding the `getItem`, `getItemId`, and `getItemCount` methods, and - i think - performing the correct check on my `onBindViewHolder` method to tell if my data is clean or not... but this last part is confusing to me, as I am unsure as to what I should be performing my conditional on (where I feel the bulk of the answers to these questions are lacking)...

**Here's some relevant code:**

```
public class MenuQueryAdapter extends ParseRecyclerQueryAdapter<MenuItem, MenuQueryAdapter.MenuViewHolder> {

    public MenuQueryAdapter(ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<MenuItem> factory, boolean hasStableIds) {
        super(factory, hasStableIds);// hasStableIds set to TRUE
    }


    @Override
    public MenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MenuViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.menu_item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MenuViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MenuItem menuItem = getItem(position);
        holder.bindItem(menuItem);
    }

    @Override
    public MenuItem getItem(int position) {
        //return super.getItem(position);
        if (menuItemList != null && menuItemList.size() > 0) {
            return menuItemList.get(position);
        }
        return super.getItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    // View Holder
    public static class MenuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        MenuItem menuItem;

        TextView title;
        TextView price;
        TextView summary;
        TextView itemCount;

        TextView  calorieLabel;
        TextView  proteinLabel;
        TextView  fatLabel;
        TextView  carbsLabel;
        TextView  fiberLabel;

        ParseImageView imageView;

        private String objectId = "";
        private boolean active = true;
        private boolean inStock = true;
        private boolean cSoon = false;
        private boolean hasNutrition = false;


        MenuViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_title_label);
            price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_price_label);
            summary = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_summary);

            calorieLabel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_label_calorie_value);
            proteinLabel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_label_protein_value);
            fatLabel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_label_fat_value);
            carbsLabel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_label_carbs_value);
            fiberLabel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_label_fibre_value);

            imageView = (ParseImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_main_image);

            // Containers
            final RelativeLayout activeView = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_top_view_active);
            final RelativeLayout inactiveView = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_top_view_inactive);

            View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    active = !active;
                    if(active)
                    {
                        activeView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        inactiveView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        activeView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        inactiveView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            };

            final RelativeLayout topView = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_top_view);
            topView.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            final ImageButton info = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_info_button);
            info.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

        }

        public void bindItem(MenuItem item) {
            menuItem = item;

            menuItem.populateData(); // gets data from DB

            // THIS IS MY CHECK TO SEE IF THE DATA SHOULD EB RECYCLED
            if( !menuItem.getTitle().equals(enroot.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.menu_title)) ) {
                title.setText(menuItem.getTitle());
                price.setText(String.valueOf(menuItem.getPrice()));
                summary.setText(menuItem.getSummary());
                calorieLabel.setText(menuItem.getCalories());
                proteinLabel.setText(menuItem.getProtein());
                fatLabel.setText(menuItem.getFat());
                carbsLabel.setText(menuItem.getCarbs());
                fiberLabel.setText(menuItem.getFibre());
                imageView.setParseFile(menuItem.getImage());
                imageView.loadInBackground();

                if (menuItem.getInt(EnrootConstants.kERItemInStockKey) <= 0) {
                    inStock = false;
                }
                if (menuItem.getBoolean(EnrootConstants.kERItemComingSoonKey) && inStock) {
                    cSoon = true;
                }
                if (menuItem.getList(EnrootConstants.kERItemNutritionKey) != null && menuItem.getList(EnrootConstants.kERItemNutritionKey).size() > 0) {
                    hasNutrition = true;
                }

                // Id
                objectId = menuItem.getObjectId();
                if (mOnItemChangedListener != null) {
                    mOnItemChangedListener.passIdToActivity(objectId);
                }

                // Stock
                RelativeLayout ooStock = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_soldout);
                if (!inStock) {
                    ooStock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                // Coming Soon
                RelativeLayout comingSoon = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_comingsoon);
                if (cSoon) {
                    comingSoon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                // Nutrition
                if (!hasNutrition) {
                    RelativeLayout nutritionOverlay = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_nutrition_group);
                    nutritionOverlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                // Minus
                final ImageButton minus = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_btn_minus);
                if (inStock && !cSoon) {
                    minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if (mOnItemChangedListener != null) {
                                mOnItemChangedListener.onPriceSubtracted(objectId, getAdapterPosition());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    minus.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    minus.setEnabled(false);
                    minus.setClickable(false);
                }

                // Plus
                final ImageButton plus = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_btn_plus);
                if (inStock && !cSoon) {
                    plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if (mOnItemChangedListener != null) {
                                mOnItemChangedListener.onPriceAdded(objectId, getAdapterPosition());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    plus.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    plus.setEnabled(false);
                    plus.setClickable(false);
                }
            }
            else {
                clearItem();
            }
        }

        void clearItem() {

            title.setText("");
            price.setText("");
            summary.setText("");
            calorieLabel.setText("");
            proteinLabel.setText("");
            fatLabel.setText("");
            carbsLabel.setText("");
            fiberLabel.setText("");

            objectId = "";
            active = true;
            inStock = true;
            cSoon = false;
            hasNutrition = false;

        }

    } /* eoc holder */

    } /* eoc adapter */
```

So... I see a lot of talk about simply overriding the `getItem` and/or `getItemId` (which makes sense if you have Stable Ids), but that doesn't seem to have any effect. I've even had `setIsRecyclable` set to false on the `ViewHolder`, to no effect.

I'm stuck... would love to hear if I'm doing something dreadfully wrong...

Comment: Try call clearItem always instead only if your title condition fails. Also check your title condition it looks strange that the current title is compared with a static title.

Comment: The comparison with the static title is because I use that string resource as the text for the XML view - if I set it to null, I wouldn't be able to see it, so that's a placeholder. So this is in place of !TextUtils.isEmpty() etc

Comment: So... always clear? Then on what condition do I set the values of my data object?

Comment: What populates `menuItemList`?

Comment: Ah. That was an experiment, you can ignore that... but essentially it is populated by the query result I get from my Database. The underlying class which this Adapter subclasses from - and which itself sits upon RecyclerView already has these items in a genericly typed list...

Comment: I don't know your data but common is that they have different titles. Check if current holder title same like item title. When yes you can skip. When not clearItem and set the new properties

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to return item counts

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
   return menuItemList.size();
}
```

Comment: No, that's not it - this is addressed in the middle are class I have between my adapter and the recycler view...